# Why second exception is not working in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, error-handling, try-except

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

for x in range(60,61):
    url = 'https://example.com/page/'
    r = requests.get(url+str(x), headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')

    articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='blog-view')
    
    for item in articles:
        title = item.find('h2', class_="entry-title").text
        
        if title == "Premium" or title == "Deleted" or title == "deleted":
            image_url = "None"
        else:
            try:
                image_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.img['src']
            except TypeError:
                image_url = item.find('div', class_='wp-caption').img['src']
            except AttributeError:
                image_url = "None"
            print(image_url)
```

Output

```
TypeError
Cell In [10], line 30
     29 try:
---> 30     image_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.img['src']
     31 except TypeError:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError
Cell In [10], line 32
     30     image_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.img['src']
     31 except TypeError:
---> 32     image_url = item.find('div', class_='wp-caption').img['src']
     33 except AttributeError:
     34     image_url = "None"

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'img
```

I am a newbie, I have given 2 exceptions one for `TypeError` and another for `AttributeError` so at the end I should get `"None"` in the output.

But somehow the 2nd exception is not executing. In python, we can give as many exceptions as we can but in this case, 2nd exception is not executing. why? Is this because of for loop or indentation?

Comment: The error is on the code in the `except` block. There is nothing to catch this exception.

Comment: You could add an inner `try…except` block around the additional attempt and then indent your second exception to that new inner block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `except` should be nested in the first `except` - currently it is not, hence you get that error. Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

for x in range(60,61):
    url = 'https://example.com/page/'
    r = requests.get(url+str(x), headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features='lxml')

    articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='blog-view')
    
    for item in articles:
        title = item.find('h2', class_="entry-title").text
        
        if title == "Premium" or title == "Deleted" or title == "deleted":
            image_url = "None"
        else:
            try:
                image_url = item.find('div', class_='entry-content').p.img['src']
            except TypeError:
                try:
                    image_url = item.find('div', class_='wp-caption').img['src']
                except AttributeError:
                    image_url = "None"
            print(image_url)
```

If you still have issues, confirm the actual url, and your end goal (what are you after?), and I will update my answer.